# Как выбрать только по одному уникальному значению из столбца

Tags: android, sqlite

У меня есть запрос к БД, запрашиваю все данные из одного столбца. В столбце есть значения, к примеру, {яблоко, груша, яблоко, груша, груша}. Как получить на выходе только 2 значения груша и яблоко? т.е. сколько бы раз не повторялось значение на выходе оно должно быть одним. Нашел в интернете, что можно использовать `DISTINCT`, но никак не могу понять как именно

вот собственно сам запрос

```
public Cursor get_data_from_table()
{
    return MyDB.query(DB_TABLE_1,
            new String[] {COLUMN_1},
            null, null, null, null, null
            );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать метод класса `Cursor`, который имеет следующую сигнатуру:

```
Cursor query(boolean distinct, String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit)
```

Т.е., Вам нужно добавить первым параметром `boolean`-значение `true`:

```
public Cursor get_data_from_table()
{
    return MyDB.query(true,
            DB_TABLE_1,
            new String[] {COLUMN_1},
            null, null, null, null, null, null
            );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

В вашем случае можно использовать group by - чтобы объединить все одинаковые значения, и order by - что сделать сортировку.

```
MyDB.query(DB_TABLE_1,new String[] {COLUMN_1},null, null, COLUMN_1, null, COLUMN_1);
```